# Module inside With, With inside Module, or Just Module?

Tags: performance-tuning, programming, scoping, variable-definitions, variable

In general, if one wants to define local variables and local constants, which of the following is the best programming practice in terms of performance and code "safety"? (Assume `Block` is not appropriate.)

1. `With` inside `Module`
2. `Module` inside `With`
3. Define constants along with variables using just `Module`

### Bonus Question

Is the answer the same if `Block` is appropriate in place of `Module`?

Comment: I'd say `With` outermost and `Module` as inner as possible, even if that means using nested `With`s. (Reason: immutable beats mutable.) And avoid `Block` unless you know why you must use it.
But I'll listen to whatever the CS guys have to say.

Comment: @Alan When you say “Immutable beats mutable”, you mean performance-wise. Correct?

Comment: [Related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs), also you can 'chain' locals with `With`, e.g. `With[{a = 2}, {b=a^2}, {c=b^2},  c]`

Comment: @JustSomeOldMan I think 'immutable beats mutable' is from the point of view of debuggability and reasoning about your program, guaranteeing that immutable variables won't change, confining bug prone mutability to fewer lines of code. The performance differences are small.